# Не выводит данные ANGULAR PHP MVC

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, pdo, angular5

У меня есть вью, которое выводит данные.

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-body">
    <form action="" class="form-horizontal" name="contractsInfo" data-ng-submit="saveContracts()">
        <input type="hidden" id="idContract" data-ng-model="idContract">
        <legend class="text-primary"> <i class="fas fa-edit fa-cog"></i> Редактирование контракта</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="dpName" class="form-label"><b>Название отделения</b> </label>
                <input type="text" data-ng-model="dpName" id="dpName" class="form-control" disabled>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="numberContract" class="form-label"><b>Номер контракта</b>
                </label>
                <input type="text" data-ng-model="numberContract" id="numberContract" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Введите номер контракта">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="nameContract" class="form-label"><b>Предмет контракта</b> </label>
                <input type="text" id="nameContract" data-ng-model="nameContract" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Введите предмет контракта">
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="dateConclusion" class="form-label"><b>Дата заключения контракта</b>
                </label>
                <input type="date" data-ng-model="dateConclusion" 

id="dateConclusion" class="form-control">
                </div>

//выводим сюда второй запрос
                <input type="text" data-ng-model="stage" id="stage" class="form-control">
```

Angular

```
app.controller('contractsController', function($scope, $http, $window){


$scope.getInfoByContractID = function(id) {
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url:  "http://localhost/cabinet/contracts/getContracts",
        params: {id: id}
    }).then(function(result,stageContract){
        window.scrollTo(0, 100);

        $scope.idContract = result.data.idContract;
       
        $scope.dpName= result.data.departmentName;
        $scope.numberContract= result.data.numberContract;
        $scope.nameContract= result.data.nameContract;
      
        $scope.dateConclusion= new Date(result.data.dateConclusion);

      //Второй запрос
      $scope.stage= stageContract[1].data.id_stage;                                                                    
        
        
    })
}
```

Controller

```
    public function getContracts () {
    if(!$_SESSION['user']){
        header("Location: /");
        return;
    }

    if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
        echo json_encode(array("success" =>false));
    } else {
        $contactId = $_GET['id'];
        $contractInfo = json_encode($this->model->getContractById($contactId));
    
        echo $contractInfo;
  
      

    }
}
```

И модел (sql1 - второй запрос)

```
   public function getContractById($id){
   $result = array();

   $sql= "SELECT
   contract.idContract,
   department.departmentName,
   contract.numberContract,
   contract.nameContract,
   contract.dateConclusion
 FROM contract
   INNER JOIN department
     ON contract.department = department.idDepartment
 WHERE contract.idContract = :idContract";

 $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bindValue(":idContract", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $stmt->execute();
 $result=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 return $result;

 $sql1 = "SELECT * from stage WHERE contracrt = :idContract";
 $stmt1 = $this->db->prepare($sql1);
 $stmt1->bindValue(":idContract", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $stmt1->execute();

 while($row = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $stageContract[$row['id_stage']] = $row;
    }


    if(isset($stageContract)){
        return $stageContract; 
    }


   
   }
```

*Во вью выводится только первый запрос из модели ($sql), а второй ($sql1) не выводится. Я предполагаю, что в первом же запросе возвращается одна строка, а во втором несколько и я пытаюсь его засунуть в ассоциативный массив. Как правильно его вывести, подскажите, пожалуйста!*

Сейчас это выглядит так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И нужно еще как-то сделать, чтобы инпуты генерировались исходя из того, сколько строк вернул запрос..
потому что stage может быть много. :( Я понимаю, как это можно сделать просто на скриптах PHP, но в MVC c ANGULAR ничего не получается :(

Comment: `$sql1 = "SELECT * from stage WHERE contracrt = :idContract";` Зело похоже на очепятку в имени поля...

Comment: @Akina, опечатки нет, имя поля называется contracrt .....

Comment: После `return $result;` код не работает и работать не должен